# read_sql failing on table name

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

Apologies if it is a repeat, I could not find a related question based on my search.

I am trying to load data from a MS SQL Server and the following works:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(driver='SQL Server', 
                        server=server_name, 
                        database=database_name, 
                        trusted_connection='yes')

df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM MyTables.Table1', connection)
```

However, this fails:

```
df = pd.read_sql('MyTables.Table1', connection)
```

with error:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'MyTables.Table1': ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The request for procedure 'Table1' failed because 'Table1' is a table object. (2809) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

I understand that `read_sql_table()` needs a `SQLAlchemy` connection to make this work but I thought `read_sql()` would work with `pyodbc` connection?

How would reading from table_name work with `read_sql()`?

Comment: What's the reason not to use the first `read_sql()` statement? AS that one is working...

Comment: Because `read_sql()` is just a wrapper for `read_sql_table()` and `read_sql_query()`. It will default to whichever one makes sense based on what you feed it. So it is actually using `read_sql_table()` behind the scenes...which requires a SQLAlchemy connection. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.read_sql.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.read_sql_table.html#pandas.read_sql_table